# How to capture bash command output using python script

Tags: python

How to capture bash command output using python script.

For eg:

running below in linux :

```
[root@xxxxxx oracle]# echo sumit                                                                                                                         
sumit
[root@xxxxxx oracle]#
```

How can i re print only the above output using python script ? like running python test.py shoud give 'sumit' as output. i tried below:

test.py :

```
import sys

sys.stdout.flush()
out = sys.stdin.readline()

print(out)
```

Above prints only the input i type but not the already displayed output

Comment: Use the `subprocess` module to execute shell commands from Python and capture the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `subprocess`, you can run commands and check their return code, stdout and stderr outputs. Would that help?

For example:

```py
import subprocess as proc
    
byte_output = proc.check_output(["ls", "-1", "."])
str_output = str(byte_output, "utf-8")
print(str_output)
# prints my local folders dev\ngit
```